# Creating a global variable to all the controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a base URL common to all my controllers. I want to declare this as a variable in one place, and use it in all my controllers. That will make any future updates fast and simple. Is that possible? I'm declaring it in all my controllers like this:

```
@baseURL = "www.url.com/something/"
```

Comment: Why not just use `root_url` and related (`link_to` and `url_for`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, all your controllers will inherit from `ApplicationController`. You may then define the variable there, making it available to its descendants.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  BASE_URL = "www.url.com/something/"
end
```

Answer (score 10):

In your application controller.

```
before_action :set_variables

def set_variables
 @baseURL = "www.url.com/something/"
end
```

This `@baseURL` instance variable will be accessible in all your actions and views as you make all controllers inherit the ApplicationController.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a method inside `ApplicationController` and use that method like a helper_method to access it from the views.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :base_url
  def base_url
    @base_url ||= "www.url.com/something/"
  end
end
```

I try to avoid before_actions to setup variables.
Inside your controllers and views you will able to call the `base_url` method.

It's the same to include this method in the `application_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Rails controllers inherit from ApplicationController. Try putting it there:

```
def baseUrl
 @baseURL = "www.url.com/something/"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class variable in your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  @@baseURL = "www.url.com/something/"

  def self.baseURL
    @@baseURL
  end
end

class SomeFrontendController < ApplicationController

end
```

Within all your controllers now you could access @@baseURL or call the class method:

```
SomeFrontendController.baseURL
# => "www.url.com/something/"
```

**But** this is dirty. **Better** use a constant:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  BASE_URL = "www.url.com/something/"
end

class SomeFrontendController < ApplicationController

end
```

Within all your controllers now you could access BASE_URL or:

```
SomeFrontendController::BASE_URL
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one variable and you are **sure**, that you need it only within controllers scope declaring a constant in `ApplicationController` should be enough:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  BASE_URL = "www.url.com/something/"
end

class SomeOtherController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @base_url = BASE_URL
  end
end
```

However usually custom URLs (and other things like email addresses) earlier or later are needed in other parts of an application so it is useful to have a single source of truth by using gem like https://github.com/settingslogic/settingslogic and store all such variables in one place (file).